# error dateTimeField input format

Tags: python, django

Why does django give me an error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_formats' at 
start_time=models.DateTimeField(input_formats='%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
```

Is there something wrong with the input format? what should i do if i want the format input to be `date - month - year hour minute`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have confused [model DateTimeFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) and [form DateTimeFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields). Models don't take `input_formats` arguments, forms do.

From [Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#working-with-forms):
the form library and API (which is what it sounds like you want) is to help you create HTML forms, do input validation, etc.

From [Models and databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/#module-django.db):
A model is the single, definitive source of data about your data. It contains the essential fields and behaviors of the data you’re storing. Generally, each model maps to a single database table

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true anymore. I recently upgraded to Django 1.11 and I'm also now getting this error, raised from `django/forms/fields.py in __init__`.

Answer (score 0):

The [`models.DateTimeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField) doesn't take any arguments passed to it called `input_formats`.

What you're looking for is [`form.DateTimeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield), for example:

```
form.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d-%m-%y %H:%M',])
```

The formats must be in a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `input_formats` is a property of `form.DateTimeField()` and not `models.DateTimeField()`
2. According to [the Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField.input_formats) `input_formats` must be a list or a tuple.